# Java: Accessing object's elements within a multi-dimensional Arrylist

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I stored objects with 3 attributes in a 2-dimensional ArrayList, but I don't know how to access/read them from the ArrayList.

My code so far: Creating the object class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TwoDimMatrix {

    private class MyObject{
        private String attr1;
        private String attr2;
        private String attr3;
        public String getAttr1() {
            return attr1;
        }
        public void setAttr1(String attr1) {
            this.attr1 = attr1;
        }
        public String getAttr2() {
            return attr2;
        }
        public void setAttr2(String attr2) {
            this.attr2 = attr2;
        }
        public String getAttr3() {
            return attr3;
        }
        public void setAttr3(String attr3) {
            this.attr3 = attr3;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TwoDimMatrix matrix = new TwoDimMatrix ();
        Integer lines = 5;
        Integer rows = 5;

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> twodimmat = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<lines ; i++)
        {
            twodimmat.add(new ArrayList<Object>());
            for(int j=0; j < rows ; j++)
            {
                MyObject obj = matrix.new MyObject();
                obj.setAttr1("36");
                obj.setAttr2("24m");
                obj.setAttr3("2H");
                twodimmat.get(i).add(obj);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(twodimmat.get(0).get(1));
    }

}
```

I only get 'MyObject' but how can I read the values stored in attributes e.g. Attr1  or Attr2? When trying to access with the getter method I get a compiler error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method getAttr1() is undefined for the type Object
```

I can assign the objects in the ArrayList to an instance of type object but not to an instance of MyObject, hence I have no access to the getter method of `MyObject`. It seems to me I can save `MyObject` in an `ArrayList` as `Object` type only, which means losing all methods of `MyObject`. The values are still there (please see attached screenshot) but how to read them?

[How to access the attribute 'attr1' of 'itemObj'?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFKzR.png)

Thanks!

Comment: `twodimmat.get(0).get(1).getAttr1()` & `twodimmat.get(0).get(1).getAttr2()`

Comment: @ takendarkk thanks for your suggestion. I have added to my first post the compiler error I get when using the getter method of `MyObject`. Any idea what the reason is?

Comment: You need to specify what is in your array list. declare it as `ArrayList<ArrayList<MyObject>> twodimmat` otherwise you're just getting an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most basic class in java is an Object.

```
Runnable a = ()->System.out.println("a");
```

`a` is an Object that implements runnable.

```
Object b = a;
```

`b` is a, nothing has changed. Technically `b` has the method run but we've written it so that we cannot see the method.

```
a.run(); //works
b.run(); //fails at compile time.
((Runnable)b).run(); //works.
```

In your case you have MyObject,

```
MyObject obj = ...;
Object obj2 = obj;
```

Now `obj2` is actually a `MyObject` but we've hidden that fact. So if you want to use those methods you need to cast or use the original reference.

```
((MyObject)obj2).getAttr1();
```

If we don't cast then the compiler gives us an error because not all objects have a .getAttr1 method.

That is what Generics are for.

```
List<MyObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();
//add a couple objects.

MyObject obj = objects.get(0);
```

Now all of the methods of MyObject are available.

```
List<Object> broken = new ArrayList<>();

broken.add(new MyObject());
broken.add(new Object());
```

Maybe you can see the issue.

```
Object one = broken.get(0);
Object two = broken.get(1);
```

We know Object `one` is a MyObject, but `two` is not. So the compiler rightly fails to let us call. `one.getAttr1()`

```
((MyObject)one).getAttr1(); //works
((MyObject)two).getAttr1(); //fails at runtime.
```

Moral of the story. Use `List<List<MyObject>>` instead of `List<List<Object>>`

Comment: many thanks for the detailed clarification and your help! Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `MyObject` just call its methods

```
System.out.println(twodimmat.get(0).get(1).getAttr1());
System.out.println(twodimmat.get(0).get(1).getAttr2());
```

Or

```
MyObject item = twodimmat.get(0).get(1);
System.out.println(item .getAttr1());
System.out.println(item .getAttr2());
```

Comment: thank you for the idea to assign the stored object to a new `MyObject` . However this way throws an error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to TwoDimMatrix.MyObject` It seems to me that saving `MyObject` in the ListArray converts`MyObject` to a plain `Object`. The plain object carries all 3 attributes and the values. The question is how to access these attributes.

Comment: @CoffeeMaster Because you save in `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>` and create  `new ArrayList<Object>`, use MyObject instead. You create real MyObject but you just tell the code that they are Object, so method aren't accessible, you would need to cast

Comment: @ azro that's it! Thank you!